# could I mount a different manufacturer brand rotor to use with my brakes?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I've a tektro draco hydraulic brakes on my mtb and I would like to know if it is possible to mount a different brand rotor to use with my brakes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The brand of brake doesn't matter. The only variables you should care about are:

1. Rotor diameter. You should probably get the same size as the old one; for a different size, you'll need an adapter to reposition the brake calipers.
2. The way the rotor attaches to the hub. Most of them are held on with 6 bolts, but a few use the "Centerlock" attachement which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Could I use any adapters?, or do I need the ones that matches the calipers brand?. I would like to upgrade to 200mm and is hard to find those tektro draco adapters.

Comment: You have to match the caliper brand.  It's the fork/frame end of the adapter that is standardised, but the caliper mounts tend to be proprietary.

Comment: @cmannett85: they're not standardized, but I *think* there's only a small number of variations.

Comment: @yeforriak: I'm not sure. You should post a separate question, maybe someone will know. Before you do, measure the distance between the mounting bolt holes (you might need measuring calipers).

Answer (score 2):

As long as the bolt pattern is the same and the rotor is the same size, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a separate answer only because I can't vote or comment on other's answers yet.

Speaking directly to the original question... yes - it is possible.  I have a winter set of wheels with a rotor by a different maker and it is a center lock mount vs. a six-bolt mount of my regular wheels.  No problem at all and it is one of the main things I like about disk brakes.  With rim brakes I would have to adjust the brakes each time I did the switch-a-roo unless both sets of wheels had exactly the same width.  Since the winter wheels have studded tires I make the switch on clear/dry days in the winter as well.